# What I'm doing wrong? if statement with scanf not working properly with input

Tags: c

I am trying to develop a small program which is available below:
When I run the program, even after the right input, it gives me the output described in else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char course;

    printf("Enter Your Course Name: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &course);

    if (course == 'TOEFL') {
        printf("Yes, you are eligible \n");
    } else {
        printf("You Can Not Join Us \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `course == 'TOEFL'`....Please re-read a C book.

Comment: Put `#include <sring.h>`. `char course;` --> `char course[16];`, `scanf(" %s", &course);` --> `scanf(" %15[^\n]%*c", course);`, `if (course == 'TOEFL'){` --> `if (strcmp(course, "TOEFL")==0){`

Comment: I know I'm newbie and asking a very basic question here. But rather than mocking, can you please suggest how this kind of thing can work? All I want is to take input and verify it. So any suggestion with solution would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a balance thing. You are asking a question that would be very easy to google on your own.

Comment: Any answer to this question would have to teach you how arrays and strings work in C, basically several chapters of a C book. Therefore the question is too broad  - this site isn't an interactive beginner tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

```
scanf(" %c", &course);
```

But also,

1. Strings in c MUST be wrapped with double qoutes, the expression `'TOEFL'` must be generating a warning about multi character constant, do not ignore it.
2. Strings in c, are compared one character at a time, so you need to use a function called `strcmp()` for that.
3. To read a string, you need an array to store it in, and yes, the `"%s"` specifier

   ```
   char cours[100];
   scanf("%99s", course);

   if (strcmp(course, "TOEFL") == 0) ...
   ```

Comment: and you can;t use `==` to compare strings. :)

Answer (score 0):

course is a char variable, so it only can contain a single character. 
Try changing its declaration to:

```
char course[10];
```

Answer (score -2):

See my code comments for explaination //xxxxxx below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char course; //this decl stores only single character not string

    printf("Enter Your Course Name: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &course); //passing string argument 

    if (course == 'TOEFL') {//can't compare strings with == use strcmp
        printf("Yes, you are eligible \n");
    } else {
        printf("You Can Not Join Us \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```